# How to install src-0.0.7 package?

Tags: python, pip

I am building a environment for running code, the code "import src" which is not in colab, or my PC. I saw the PyPl page, it says I should run 'pip install src', but I still cannot make it.

```
(base) oblic@oblic-PC:~$ pip install src
Collecting src
  Using cached src-0.0.7.zip (6.3 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: src
  Building wheel for src (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/oblic/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-m62_ocqn
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/
  Complete output (41 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/src
  copying src/__init__.py -> build/lib/src
  running egg_info
  writing src.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to src.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to src.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'src.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py", line 96, in <module>
      'install_lib': InstallCommand,
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 226, in run
      reinit_subcommands=True)
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 198, in reinitialize_command
      cmd = _Command.reinitialize_command(self, command, reinit_subcommands)
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 306, in reinitialize_command
      reinit_subcommands)
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 950, in reinitialize_command
      for sub in command.get_sub_commands():
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 324, in get_sub_commands
      if method is None or method(self):
    File "/home/oblic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 631, in has_lib
      return (self.distribution.has_pure_modules() or
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_pure_modules'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for src
  Running setup.py clean for src
Failed to build src
Installing collected packages: src
    Running setup.py install for src ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/oblic/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4y4re6aq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/oblic/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/src
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/
    Complete output (2 lines):
    running install
    You've probably made a mistake here and are trying to install from a 'src' directory which doesn't exist.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/oblic/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qffzaygw/src/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4y4re6aq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/oblic/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/src Check the logs for full command output.
```

Above is the output when I tried to setup the package 'src'.
I don't know if I can post this or not.

Comment: What is the output of `pip install src` ? Where are you executing this command ?

Comment: I just ran this in ubuntu terminal and also tried it in google colab.
and it outputs :
Building wheel for src (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
and a lot of red comments

Comment: The ``src`` package is a dummy package. If your *code* depends on ``import src``, it does *not* use the ``src`` package available via ``pip``. Consult whoever wrote the colab code in the first place to find out which package is needed, and how to get it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ahhha, Yes, you are right, there is indeed a folder named 'src', now I have a try to import the file from this folder.

Comment: See also https://github.com/mitchellrj/src/issues/3

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, all of you. You really helped me to figure out what the question is. Now let me make this clear, and hopefully this case could help others.

The codes I want to run actually are contained in a dictionary called 'src'.
and the programmer wrote their code, for example main.py, with following line:
'''
import src.utils as utils
'''
I made a mistake that I ran the code in the ~/main/src dictionary, so python returned an error "no src module". I was then stupid to find src package.

Actually, one easy way to run the codes is copying all the .py files to the upper level dictionary, in my case ~/main/, and run main.py in ~/main/, because ~/main/src/ contains utils.py, then the code will run smoothly, and no module missing at all.

Comment: Perhaps, now you should accept own answer, as it was really helpful.

Comment: ㅠㅠ same situation