# unable to install src package

Tags: python, pip

I was using the command `pip install src==0.0.6` to install a package but running in to build errors, following is the error, i couldnt able to identify whats causing the issue.  please help

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wc7cw0_8\src_2495d167acee48ce85df5c97aa5243b3\setup.py", line 70, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 301, in run
          install = self.reinitialize_command('install',
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 208, in reinitialize_command
          cmd = _Command.reinitialize_command(self, command, reinit_subcommands)
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 305, in reinitialize_command
          return self.distribution.reinitialize_command(command,
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 950, in reinitialize_command
          for sub in command.get_sub_commands():
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 324, in get_sub_commands
          if method is None or method(self):
        File "C:\Users\punen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 654, in has_lib
          return (self.distribution.has_pure_modules() or
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_pure_modules'
      [end of output]
```

Comment: what if trying without version?, just `pip install src` ?

Comment: same, but with extra errors like " Running setup.py install for src did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      running install
      You've probably made a mistake here and are trying to install from a 'src' directory which doesn't exist.
      [end of output]"

Comment: Do you have a folder called src in the current cwd of the terminal ??

Comment: no such folder in my cwd

Comment: Also take a look also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640592/how-to-install-src-0-0-7-package

Comment: ok this really helped, at first when i read this i though he was refering to his code, so basically "pip install src" doesnt work,  I have to download the package and import it manaully :)

Comment: I think you did not understand the problem. SRC package does not exist, it's a dummy package that avoids you to install SRC folder by mistake.